# Cassandra Prepared Statement and NodeFailure

Tags: cassandra, prepared-statement

I am using Cassandra for one of my application.
I would like to use Prepared statement that Cassandra provides through cql.
If I prepared a query,Is this is prepared in all nodes?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a little brief. Please show some more efforts, such as examplle code

Comment: K.. I am thinking about node failure scenario that can come while running. I don't know exactly how prepared statement works in this distributed nature. I have two thoughts. one is , prepared statement is get prepared in single node and all rest of the queries are forwarded to the same node. Second one is , prepared statement is prepared in all nodes and client request does not have any restriction in selecting coordinator node. If second case is right , Cassandra prepares statement can tolerate node failure .

Comment: Please help me on the below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134514/cassandra-querying-reducing-performance/52139204?noredirect=1#comment91235494_52139204

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it is BUT assuming you're using the Datastax Java driver, the driver will have you covered because it will attempt to re-prepare the statement when needed. See the handling of case *UNPREPARED* in [RequestHandler.SpeculativeExecution#onSet](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/RequestHandler.java#L532) and the use of the *prepareAndRetry* callback.